# Accent on psbarcode and Mecard (QR)

Tags: accents, pst-barcode, barcodes

I am currently trying to build some QR code using `pst-barcode`. I will use it for communicate my contact details. Thus, I have used the `\psbarcode` command.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(1.2in,1.2in)
\psbarcode{MECARD\string:N\string:Doé,John\string;\string;}%
       {eclevel=L width=1.161 height=1.161}{qrcode}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, the accent `é` is not well read by my cellphone. I have tried to replace the code by the following

```
\begin{pspicture}(1.2in,1.2in)
\psbarcode{MECARD\string:N\string:Do^233,John\string;\string;}%
       {eclevel=L width=1.161 height=1.161}{qrcode}
\end{pspicture}
```

But the result in my cellphone is `Doe^233`, the ascii code seems to be not convert to the associated characters.

I also have tried the following code

```
\begin{pspicture}(1.2in,1.2in)
        \psbarcode{BEGIN:VCARD
        N:Do^233;John^010
        TEL;WORK:+1 ^040234^041 567-8910^010
        EMAIL:john@doe.com^010
        END:VCARD}
{eclevel=L width=1.161 height=1.161 parse}{qrcode}
\end{pspicture}
```

but the Vcard is not recognize by my cellphone.

So I think my cellphone has some troubles for reading well the QR code and recognize the special characters but which LaTeX code is ok with dealing with accent?

Comment: Your second exampe (spelling out the accented letter as `^233`) works if you add `parse` after the `height` attribute, like in the third example. Your third example also works insofar as the text of the vcard is transmitted as spelled out; whether the receiving device recognizes it as an address or not is not a LaTeX issue.

Comment: For your examples to work you don't need `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and `\usepackage{pstricks}`.

Comment: @gernot Thank you for your remarks. I have tested the `parse` option. It works. Moreover, I have change the apps on my android phone and I obtain the right accent with the non original apps. The original apps is not able to read well the accent (I think it is due to the fact my phone - a Xiaomi Redmi 3S - is a chinesesphone...).